# python sort list of objects by length of a containing list

Tags: python, list, sorting, object

I have a class which contains two lists, an int and a string.. which looks something like this

```
class Something:
    num = 0

    def __init__(self, clu, pro)
        self.clu = clu
        self.rep = []
        self.rep_dis = []
        self.pro = ""
```

Now in my main I keep a list of `Something` objects.

```
something_list = []
tmp_something = Something("this", "that")
tmp_something.rep.append("some")
tmp_something.rep_dis.append("thing")
something_list.append(tmp_something)
```

How do I sort this list by the length of the objects list `rep`?

edit: code segment format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to "how do I sort a list of objects by..." is always "use the `key` argument to `sort`".  In this case:

```
something_list.sort(key=lambda x: len(x.rep))
```

The `key` argument is a function which is called for each item in the list, and should return the value according to which you want to sort.

Comment: perfect! had to add a `reverse=True` to fit my requirements, but worked just as intended, thank you very much!

Comment: +1 This is an instance where I wish Python had a function composition operator: `from operator import attrgetter as ag; something_list.sort(key=len ∘ ag('rep'))`. Letting Python compose the functions, rather than having to define a `lambda`, would be more efficient.

Comment: @chepner: How would that be "more efficient"?

Comment: All name lookups in the body of the `lambda` are deferred until the function is called, so `len` is looked up each time. If the interpreter itself performed the composition, then the resulting function object could perform the lookup once. (This is a bad example, though, since in theory every object passed to `len` might have its own `__len__` which needs to be looked up. Something like `key=list.__len__ ∘ ag('rep')` has more potential, assuming you can guarantee that the item `ag('rep')` will return is a `list` object.

Comment: @chepner: You could inject `len` into the local namespace by passing it as an argument (`lambda x, len=len:...`).  But in general that kind of optimization goes against the dynamic grain of Python.  For the general case, it needs to look the name up every time because its value might change between calls.  Either way, an extra name lookup is pretty fast.  But this is neither here nor there with regard to the original question :-).